# Training and Prediction in Spark Streaming Machine Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, spark-streaming, dataflow

I am having a hard time understanding how we can both update the machine learning model and use it to make predictions in one spark streaming job.

This code is from Spark [StreamingLinearRegressionExample](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/dcdda19785a272969fb1e3ec18382403aaad6c91/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/StreamingLinearRegressionExample.scala) class

```py
val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream(args(0)).map(LabeledPoint.parse).cache()
val testData = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)).map(LabeledPoint.parse)

val numFeatures = 3
val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
  .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(numFeatures))

model.trainOn(trainingData)
model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).print()
```

The variable `model` is being updated in one stream and used to predict in another stream. I do not understand how the changes were done to the `model` in the `trainOn` method are reflected in `predictOnValues`.